# Tkinter configuration

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm, tkinter-layout

I'm super new to programming and I'm using pycharm as my IDE.

```
import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

Not sure why I get this error, I installed the Tk library as well and still get the error. I am using a Mac.

Comment: There are many questions on this site about this specific error. Have you read through them?

Comment: ^ yes i have but I've tried many of them and they don't work :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python3 please use

```
import tkinter
```

Comment: Thank you for responding but I tried that and it doesn't work! any more suggestions??

Comment: Try to reinstall, may be this will solve your problem.  If you are using Linux u can use below command to solve the problem ```apt-get install python3-tk ```

Answer (score 0):

Well,if you are using python 3.8,In the install Setup,it has this choice:

[image]

---

If this couldn't solve your problem,Read the python official document:[IDLE and tkinter with Tcl/Tk on macOS](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/).

Comment: with pycharm i have no idea how to do this or if its even possible, i prob sound dumb but i low-key been learning python for a few months and now school canceled so im teaching myself :(

Comment: @kerenxy This could be seen in the setup installer.

Answer (score -2):

To create a window with hello world use this

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *          # importing themed widget library

root = Tk() # creating the root master application object
label = Label(root, text="Hello World") # simple text: hello world
label.pack()                           #Places label into its parent
root.mainloop()                           # running the mainloop
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The problem is that they can't import tkinter, so of course it will be impossible to actually use tkinter.

Comment: ^ I actually can't even open the windows cause it gives me the error, thank you though !

Comment: I just wanted to say that you can import tkinter also in that  way.

Comment: No problem i appreciate it!!

Comment: but im still not able to even open a window and im lowkey getting desperate

Comment: what idle and what python version do u use

Comment: i use pycharm and its python 3.8